# Ethereum how to re-encrypt the sensitive data if the private key leaks

Tags: ethereum

Assuming some sensitive data is encrypted by the public key and stored on the ethereum network.

My question is:
If the private key leaks, can we re-encrypt the data so that the data cannot be decrypted by the leaked private key?

Since the immutability of the blockchain, I thinks it's impossbile, right?

Are there any other good solutions for storing the sensitive data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the private key leaks, can we re-encrypt the data so that the data cannot be decrypted by the leaked private key?

You could reencrypt the data with a new private key, and write that new encrypted data to the blockchain. However, since ethereum maintains a complete historical state, your previous version of the data will still be visible in the past blocks, allowing anyone to decrypt it.

> Are there any other good solutions for storing the sensitive data?

Encrypt and store the data off chain, and just publish a hash of the data to the chain for integrity/security checks/proof of time.